# Objects in this class cannot be updated outside an edit session inside ArcFM?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, arcfm

I'm trying to add a feature class in ArcMap 10.2.1 that is an ArcFM Feature Class by using a python script.

I am working inside an ArcFM session which is required to edit the layer I am working with, however it is complaining about me not being in a session...

This is my script:

```
import arcpy

# fc is a point feature class
#
fc = r"Database Connections\DATABASE.sde\ACE.Electric_Network_Features\ACE.Transformer"
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@XY"])
xy = (22000,99000)
```

Here is my exception:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
RuntimeError: Objects in this class cannot be updated outside an edit session [ACE.Transformer]
```

Am I missing a step?  I've tried looking up how to make an edit session for ArcFM in code but I have not been successful in finding this information...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ArcFM makes Python scripting a bit of a pain.

You will need to include some additional scripts that Scheider Electric provides in order to check out an ArcFM license before you begin editing.

Here's a [link to download](https://myarcfm.schneider-electric.com/s/article/How-To-Work-With-ArcFM-features-in-Python) the scripts.

Because you're on 10.2.1, you will only need to download `enumerations.py` and `ArcFMSampleUpdated.py`. And, as the link mentions, you will also need to install [Python for Windows Extensions (pywin32).](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)

Once you have the scripts downloaded and `pywin32` installed, I suggest creating a root folder that houses your project.

So, you'll need to have:

```
root folder
--- yourscript.py
--- enumerations.py
```

And then inside `yourscript.py` you need to include:

```
import arcpy
from arcgisscripting import create
from win32com.client import Dispatch
gp = create(10.1)

app = Dispatch("Miner.Framework.Dispatch.MMAppInitializeDispatch")
au = Dispatch("Miner.Framework.Dispatch.MMAutoupdaterDispatch")
runtime = Dispatch("Miner.Framework.Dispatch.MMRuntimeEnvironmentDispatch")

from enumerations import mmRuntimeMode,mmLicensedProductCode,mmAutoUpdaterMode

runtime.RuntimeMode = mmRuntimeMode.mmRuntimeModeArcServer
app.Initialize(mmLicensedProductCode.mmLPArcFM)
au.AutoUpdaterMode = mmAutoUpdaterMode.mmAUMNoEvents

workspace = "your workspace"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace

edit = arcpy.da.Editor(arcpy.env.workspace)
edit.startEditing(False, True)
edit.startOperation()

##############################
###### Your Script here ######
##############################

edit.stopOperation()
edit.stopEditing(True)

app.Shutdown
del app, runtime, au
```

The code above is also listed in the `ArcFMSampleUpdated.py` script that you downloaded, but I did add the `arcpy.da.Editor()` portion.

Comment: Does this work for 10.3.1 or do you know of an updated post?

Comment: I'm actually not sure. We've since moved to NISC.